# creating a global variable in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am validating a form, and need to look up emails, through ajax, to check if it is already being used. It all works fine, except that when it sets the variable, it is not being used through the rest of the function

```
$('#account_text_update').click(function(e){ // signup
errors = 0;
// email validation
email = $('#account_email').val();
if(email.length==0) errors = account_error('#account_email','Please enter an email address');
else {
    regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if(email.match(regex) == null) errors = account_error('#account_email','Please enter a valid email address');
    else {
        $.ajax({ // check if email already used
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax/account-email.php',
            data    : 'email='+email,
            success : function(data) {
                if(data=='yes') errors = account_error('#account_email','Email already exists');
            }
        });
    }
}
if(errors==0) update();
});
```

So the variable is `errors` it is initially set to 0, and if the ajax email check says that the email is already in use, it sets the `errors` variable. However, when it comes to update, even if there is an error, it will still update.

How can I make the ajax variable global throughout the rest of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, AJAX request is asynchronous (non-blocking), which means that the "success" function is called when the ajax request has finished (it has received a response). The browser won't wait for them to be completed in order to continue its work.

If you want to reuse the ajax response later within your code, then you must use `$.ajax({async:false})`, which will lock the browser and make a synchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to avoid using global variables as much as possible, possibly rewrite the whole code block.

For your specific problem, it is related to the concept of [Promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/). The last line:

```
if(errors==0) update();
```

will get executed before your ajax call finishes its success callback. Because of that, `errors` will always be zero and `update()` get called immediately.

There are a few ways to solve this
Either move this line into the success callback:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data == 'yes')
        errors = account_error('#account_email', 'Email already exists');
    if(errors==0) update();
}
```

Or, pipe it at the end of your [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
var validateAjax = $.ajax(...)
//...
validateAjax..always(function(){ if(errors==0) update(); });
```

Comment: so the variable errors can be read in ajax? Even though previously set outside of the ajax function?

Comment: Yes, since you're setting it as global it can be read from anywhere

Comment: how do u set as global? what is the difference

Comment: @Source, please see my answer to use a JS variable globally.